# Setting more than one argument for NSInvocationOperation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsinvocationoperation

`-[NSInvocationOperation initWithTarget:selector:object:]` only accepts one object to be passed as an argument for the method that will be called. I want to use two arguments; how can I do that?

This is my code:

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(requestRemoteImage:)
                                        object:imageURL];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
}

- (void)requestRemoteImage:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(placeImageInUI:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3's answer is exactly correct, but I would strongly discourage using `NSInvocationOperation` unless you have a strong need for it. `NSBlockOperation` is much faster to generate, easier to code, and more flexible. Invocations are extremely expensive to create, and have been widely replaced with blocks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could send a dictionary with all the values you want

Comment: Develop your answer a little, above all when it's for a new user who may not be as experimented as you

Comment: @Geoffroy  You're right .
but I try to apply it and succeeded .

Comment: @besharkhalid no problem, I was just reviewing new answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an NSInvocation object to initialize the opertation:

```
- (id)initWithInvocation:(NSInvocation *)inv
```

(NSInvocation can handle multiple arguments); or you can wrap the needed arguments to an NSArray or NSDictionary, provided they're objects.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the operation for its [`invocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005505-RH2-SW9) and modify that before adding the operation to the queue.

```
 NSInvocation * invocation = [operation invocation];
 [invocation setArgument:&anotherObject atIndex:3];    
 // Indexes 0 and 1 are self and cmd, and you've already used index 2
```

Or, [as Rob Napier suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164400/how-can-i-use-more-than-one-argument-in-nsinvocationoperation/12164601#comment16279952_12164400), use `NSBlockOperation`, which is far more flexible and easy to use.

Comment: i want to use the new argument in requestRemoteImage method